# "To find something" vs. "to find oneself faced with something"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

What exactly is the difference in the meanings of 1 and 2?

> 1. After considering all alternatives, we **find** a variety of different accounts for X.
> 2. After considering all alternatives, we **find ourselves faced with** a variety of different accounts for X.

"To find oneself faced with x" is [frequently used](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22find%20oneself%20faced%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1995,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=SeG3WZXuI4Wk6ATWiJjQAg) for when X is a sort of problem or difficulties or unpleasant thing. Is the phrase used always like that, or that is not necessary? What exactly is the difference between it and the simple verb "find"?

Comment: I'd rather find a minotaur (at a distance) than find myself faced with a minotaur. The first is a simple observation, from which I can turn away; the second is a situation in which I am personally involved, and I must take some action.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction you're referring to is not specific to "faced with a problem".

- I find treasure.
- I find myself looking for treasure.

These are two completely different things. The distinction hinges on which definition of "find" is being used. [Refer to the OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/find):

> 1.1. Discover after a deliberate search.
>    *‘I can't find my keys’*
>    *‘the sailor and his crew were found safe and well last night’*
>
> 1.2. (**find oneself**) Discover oneself to be in a particular situation.
>   *‘phobia sufferers often find themselves virtual prisoners in their own home’*

---

Let's apply these definitions to your sentences, so that you see that these sentences have two very different meanings.

> After considering all alternatives, we find a variety of different accounts for X.
>   After considering all alternatives, **we discover** a variety of different accounts for X.

This tells us that our action (considering all alternatives) has yielded a search result (a variety of different accounts for X).

> After considering all alternatives, we find ourselves faced with a variety of different accounts for X.
>   After considering all alternatives, **we are in a particular situation**, where we are faced with a variety of different accounts for X.

This tells us that our action (considering all alternatives) has led us to be in a situation where we are faced with a problem (a variety of different accounts for X).

---

**Conclusion**

The two example sentences you provided have very different meanings. Although they both use the verb "to find", it is being used in a completely different way.

---

**Update - To directly address one of your questions**

> "To find oneself faced with x" is frequently used for when X is a sort of problem or difficulties or unpleasant thing.

I don't quite agree here. "faced with X" is indeed frequently used to imply that X is a problem. However, "to find oneself" is **unrelated** to expressing that there is a problem.

- To find oneself - To realize you're in a situation
- Faced with X - Having to deal with problem X

Just because the two can be combined to create a sentence, does not mean that one is inherently tied to the other. They express different things, and both can be used by themselves:

- I find myself feeling sad when it rains.
- Due to not having paid rent on time, I am now faced with eviction.

Comment: So, the "problem" connotation is related to "faced with". Great point! Thanks!

Comment: But is "faced with X" always used for problem/unpleasant thing? What about "facing" as in "we find ourselves facing X"? Does that use usually for problems?

Comment: @Sasan: "Facing" can be literal (we were facing a wall) or figurative (we were facing bankrupcy). [The definition of "to face"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/face), when used figuratively, always boils down to a difficult situation or a problem that needs to be overcome, so I agree that it is used in a negative context.